# I want to link the absolute link from other page into current framer webpage

Tags: web-component, framerjs

I tried to link a Youtube link in current page with button component so add link event but I can’t set link to current page.
I linked all pages with the same framer site’s other pages with “/page-name” in link.
But the absolute link such as “https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9JeDaxhoieh” are worked on new tab.

Please help me about this issue.
Thank you in advance.